# Check client certificate in nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I can issue certificates without a problem and I can get nginx to force users to provide a certificate but how do I get nginx to give me information about the certificate? Information such as name and serial number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html) covers the various SSL variables that nginx sets.

First you have to actually set `ssl_verify_client` to `on` or `optional` (depending on your requirements). Since this can only be used in an `http` or `server` block, if you only want *part* of your site protected by client certificates, you'll need to use `optional` and have the application check the verification result.

Then the verification result will be stored in `$ssl_client_verify` and the client certificate identity will be stored in `$ssl_client_s_dn`. You then only need to pass these up to your application. If you need more than the subject identity, you can pass the entire client certificate with `$ssl_client_cert`.

Comment: I'm a little frustrated with [the wiki google links me to instead](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule). I didn't realize the wiki was missing information and the docs pages are better. Thanks

Comment: The wiki has been out of date for quite a while. It had a copy of the docs made, but hasn't been updated...